# ActiveRecord Observers are not called in specified callback (Rails 3)

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

I'm having a very annoying problem with my rails observers.
There are some of them that work properly and some of them that don't.

For example, I have the FollowObserver implemented like this:

```
class FollowObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(follow)
    debugger
    PendingMail.create({
      :method => "cause_being_followed",
      :data => Marshal.dump({
        :follower_id => follow.user_id,
        :cause_id    => follow.cause_id,
      })
    })
  end
end
```

It's not called in the rails server but it is in the rails console (I don't get it why).
When I run the tests, it works as expected (it's like when running the rails server something is avoiding it to run).

I configured the application.rb as well:

```
config.active_record.observers = [
  :cause_observer, 
  :charity_follow_observer, 
  :comment_observer, 
  :follow_observer, 
  :news_observer
]
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts, you can now leave comments under questions. I removed one of your 'answers' because I could not determine which answer it should have been a comment for.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should always be triggered. I would try to replace the line `debugger` with

```
logger.debug "FollowObserver::after_create"
```

then you will be able to see in your logs whether the action is triggered correctly.
Another possible cause is that while you think the object is created, it might for some reason be invalid and is actually not created. Is that possible?